# Looking for a way to pull orders by ZIP code when some use ZIP+4 and others don't

Tags: reporting-services, zipcode

I am working on a report that pulls and totals orders based on ZIP codes. My problem is that some use ZIP+4 and others don't. So I may get a number of orders from ZIP 11751, and a separate line for 11751-1234, another for 11751-5678, etc. Does anyone know of a way to pull and aggregate based only on the first 5 digits? My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
o.OrderTrackingID,
o.status,
o.clientid,
o.spieces,
o.ClientRefNo,
o.deliverytargettodate as 'odate',
o.DCoName,
o.DCity,
o.DState,
o.Dzip
FROM xview_Orders o
WHERE odate > (GetDate() - 14) AND o.Status NOT IN ('L','D')
Order By o.dzip ASC
```

Comment: My first suggestion is to ensure all the zipcode values are the same length.  One approach would be to use a case statement to ensure column returning the Zip code all values are the same length eg

--if Zip Code is 4 Characters in length append 
--'Z' to the end to make 5 Characters in length
CASE WHEN LEN(RTRIM(o.Dzip)) = 4 THEN RTRIM(o.Dzip) + 'Z'
--otherwise only return first 5 characters of the zip code
WHEN LEN(RTRIM(o.Dzip)) > 4 THEN LEFT(o.Dzip,5) 
END AS Dzip5Characters

Comment: `substring(o.Dzip,1,5)`

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 or later and also assuming that the query you posted is supposed to be fetching the data for the report based on a parameter then extend the `WHERE` clause with something like ` AND LEFT(o.Dzip,5) = @myZipCodeParameter`